# How to write auto layouts for iPhone SE and iPhone 5S programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am using auto layout programmatically to layout my views the problem is it works well on iPhone 6s plus but on other screens such as iPhone SE, iPhone 5s and even the X don't render well. Below is my code:

```
//OK button
view.addSubview(btnOk)
    btnOk.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    btnOk.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblRateUsDesc.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    btnOk.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    btnOk.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true

//Later


view.addSubview(btnLater)
    btnLater.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    btnLater.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblRateUsDesc.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    btnLater.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    btnLater.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
```

This is how iPhone SE renders it[image: This is how iPhone SE renders it]

This is how iPhone X renders it[image: This is how iPhone X renders it]
iPhone 6s plus renders it and it is my preferred layout[image: iPhone 6s plus renders it and it is my preferred layout]

Comment: I'd suggest you do your layout in a storyboard initially, so you can easily change constraints and see immediately the effect of doing so, and view at multiple phone sizes simultaneously. If you want to do it programatically, you can just use the values you used in your storyboard and translate into code.

Comment: I suggest you not setting magic constants to width and height :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
btnOk.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```

iPhone X and iPhone SE, 5s has narrow screen. You should not add constraint to the width property. I recommend you to embed these buttons to Stack View.

iPhone 5s has 320 pt screen width. Two buttons with width 150 pt has total 300 pt width. Left 20 pt for gap and margins. It is not enough. This is the cause for overlapping.

Comment: tnx great insight from you, so what should my constraints be like when I embed these buttons in a Stack View so the all look the same across device?

Comment: You need to add only three constraints for Stack View: leading anchor, trailing anchor and Y position. Stack View distribution property should be equal to Fill Equality.